# CSS Grid - Content overlapping issue

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible to create the following layout using CSS grid?

[image: layout]

The layout itself is pretty straightforward. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar__wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar__item mb-1" [class.mt-3]="item.options.length"
        *ngFor="let item of sidebarItems; let first = first;">
        <div class="sidebar__icon ark-cursor-pointer" [class.align-self]="item.options.length" (click)="item.isExpand = !item.isExpand">
          <img [src]="item.icon" alt="icon" [class.valign--middle]="item.options.length">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar__label font--14">
          <div *ngIf="!showItemTitle"></div>
          <a class="sidebar__header pl-1" [routerLink]="item.stateName" [class.font--light]="!item.options.length" [ngClass]="{'font--11 text-uppercase sidebar__header--blue' : item.options.length}" (click)="item.isExpand = !item.isExpand"
            *ngIf="showItemTitle">{{ 'Sidebar.' + item.property + '.Title' | translate}}</a>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.options; let first = first">
            <a class="sidebar__subheader pl-1" [routerLink]="subItem.stateName" [class.mt-2]="first"
              *ngIf="showItemTitle && item.isExpand" [ngClass]="hasActiveChild(subItem)"><span>{{ 'Sidebar.' + item.property +'.'+ subItem.subtitle | translate}}</span></a>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar__wrapper,
.sidebar__item,
.sidebar__label {
  display: grid;
}

.sidebar__wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.sidebar__item {
  /* grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px; */
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  margin: 0 15px 0 8px;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

.sidebar__label {
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: .5rem;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-auto-rows: 23px;
}

.font--14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.font--11 {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.sidebar__header {
  font-weight: var(--bold-font-weight);
}

.sidebar__subheader {
  font-weight: var(--light-font-weight);
}

.sidebar__icon {
  justify-self: center;
}

.sidebar__icon img {
  height: 15px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: unset;
}

#side-bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#side-bar .active-text-bold {
  background-color: rgba(104, 131, 158, 0.31);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: .25em .125rem;
  width: calc(100% + 5px);
}

.align-self {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.valign--middle {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.sidebar__header--blue {
  color: rgba(111,140,169, 0.8) !important;
}
```

The object sidebarItems looks as such:

```
const sidebarItems = [
{
    icon: 'assets/images/icon/sidebar_time.png',
    isExpand: false,
    title: 'Gestion du temps',
    property: 'TimeManagement',
    stateName: '/time/stats',
    options: [
      {
        subtitle: 'AccountChart',
        stateName: '/accounting/accounts'
      }

    ]
  },
{
      icon: 'assets/images/icon/sidebar_contacts.png',
      property: 'Contact',
      isExpand: true,
      stateName: '/contacts/list',
      options: []
    }
];

hasActiveChild(item) {
    let className = '';
    if (location.pathname.includes(item.stateName)) {
      className = 'active-text-bold';
    }
    return className;
  }
```

The above code creates the following layout:

[image: result]

However, I'm unable to re-create the spacing on the left of each sub-item.

I've tried to name the [grid lines](https://mastery.games/post/naming-css-grid-lines/) and set the grid-column: 2/4. It somehow messes up the layout.

If you have some ideas on how I can solve this issue, please let me know. Thank you.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting a padding on the .sidebar__item?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap and I've added a left padding to the links. But as you can see in the result that I want to achieve, the box is positioned slightly in the middle of the calendar icon. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the CSS [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) property.
In your case, adding a left padding to the links should do.
Try this:

```
.sidebar__item {
  /* grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px; */
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  margin: 0 15px 0 8px;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve. I'm using Bootstrap and I've already added a left padding to the links. However, the box needs to be positioned slightly in the middle of the calendar icon as shown in the picture.